# Is there a way to display/hide alerts on bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have an alert like this in my `html` code:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
</div>
```

I want this alert to be hidden by default, it should show only on certain conditions (such as when a button is clicked). How can I do that?

Comment: if you are looking for modal in bootstrap-5, check the following url https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/

Answer (score 1):

The conditional alert display can be implemented by adding bootstrap class from display utilities i.e `d-none`

```js
const alert = document.querySelector("#customAlert");
const btn = document.querySelector("#showAlert");

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  alert.classList.remove("d-none");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="showAlert">Show Alert</button>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible d-none" id="customAlert">
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
</div>
```